# SQL HAVING COUNT WITH TWO COLUMNS

Tags: sql, group-by, sap-ase, having

I have the following tableA

```
COL1 COL2 COL3
 A    1    10-1-2019
 B    4    13-4-2019
 A    1    13-4-2019
 A    1    10-1-2019
 A    1    10-1-2019
 C    3    20-4-2020
 A    1    13-4-2019
```

I this is the sql code i wish to write but the count do not accept two elements :

```
select COL1,COL2,COL3
from TableA
group by COL1,COL2,COL3,
HAVING COUNT(COL1,COL2) > 2
```

And only the result `A 1 10-1-2019` should appear because it is the only one that have the pair COL1 COL3 with more than 2 results(in this case three times). The pair COL1 /COL3 is something like a composed primary key
How can i achieve this ?

My database is  Sybase ASE

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your expected result as well

Comment: i wrote it in the post , i want the result to be A 1 10-1-2019 , it is the only result that have more than two COL1 and COL3 equal results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select COL1, COL2, COL3
from TableA
group by COL1, COL2, COL3,
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

Perhaps you have a bad example.  But I don't see why you think you need to exclude `col2`.

Comment: yes thanks a lot that solution works but what if i do not want the col2 ?

Comment: @tt0686 . . . You can remove it from the `select`, and perhaps from the `group by`.